# Adding List data as a table to the Mail Body C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending a mail to the users from my ASP.NET MVC application.

With the mail body details, I want to add the list of data as a table to the body also.

Help is needed to guide me to resolve the issue.

**The mail is like requesting documents from the users and the required document list is on this list. This can be included record 1 or more than 1**

```
 List<ReqDocForMail> docList = new List<ReqDocForMail>();
```

Model is

```
public class ReqDocForMail
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

```
string Subject = "Document Request for Task Number ";
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sendingmailaddress", "MailNameShows");
mailMessage.To.Add(User.Email_Primary);
mailMessage.Subject = "Subject";
string Body; Body = @" 
  <html>
   <body>
    <p>Dear " + CusGen + Customer.Sur_Name + " " + Customer.Name + @",</p>
    <br />Thank you </p>
    <br />
    <br />Your Task is under processing. <br />
    <br />To continue the task you need to upload the following documents. <br />
    <br />Login to the Site and go to the <b>In Process Tasks</b>
    <br />
    <br />Open the request :" + TaskDetails.TaskNumber + @". <br />
    <br />Move to the <b>Upload Documents</b> section and upload the following documents. 
    //Here I want to show the list data [File Type | Note] as a table //
   </body>
  </html>";
```

Comment: Using foreach loop you can create table html and add it to the mail body.

Comment: Have you tried doing what you ask? Create a string with `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags generated from the list items in a loop? It's not very elegant but works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It won't work. I tried.

Comment: @DevBeginner it works. In fact, that's what you accepted as the answer even thought the actual HTML generation code is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a inherited class from `List<>` and add `GetHTML()` method to it.

pseudo code:

```
public class ReqDocForMail
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class ReqDocList: List<ReqDocForMail>
{
    public string GetHTML()
    {
        string html = "";
        foreach(ReqDocForMail doc in this)
        {
            html+= doc.Note + "";//YOUR HTML FORMATTING HERE
        }
        return html;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    ReqDocList lst = new ReqDocList();
    
    string lstHTML = lst.GetHTML();
}
```

**Approach 2**
Create an extension method to get `HTML`, again some psuedo:

```
public static class ReqDocListExtension
{
    public static string GetHTML(this List<ReqDocForMail> lst)
    {
        string html = "";
        foreach(ReqDocForMail doc in lst)
        {
            html+= doc.Note + "";//YOUR HTML FORMATTING HERE
        }
        return html;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<ReqDocForMail> lst = new List<ReqDocForMail>();
    
    string lstHTML = lst.GetHTML();
}
```

Comment: There's no relevant code here, only two identical methods. The fact that one is an extension method and the other only changes the way they're called.

Comment: its upto OP how he wants to add styling or number `<td>`s